# Exception in Swift 2.0. Why 'do'?

Tags: swift

I am curious as to why Swift language engineers have decided to go with this syntax:

```
do {
  let x = try statement that throws
  try a void statement that throws
} catch {
}
```

vs the more traditional try-catch syntax that seems to be doing exactly the same. Except that in the case of Swift, one needs to type a try for each line that throws an exception.

Answer (score 4):

They want to use `try` to call out each specific expression that can throw. I imagine the reason for this is that a common complaint about exceptions is that they're 'invisible gotos', where users can't tell what's going to throw without going and looking at the definition of every function they're using. Requiring `try` on each throwing function call, eliminates this problem.

Personally I don't think 'invisible gotos' is a valid complaint. Far from being unstructured (like `goto`), exceptions make error handling highly structured. Furthermore, if you're using exceptions correctly, you almost never need to be able to tell at a glance what functions throw. For more info, see http://exceptionsafecode.com, which discusses correct use of exceptions at length.

Given that they want `try` to be an explicit call out for throwing function calls, they probably didn't want to reuse it for traditional `try`-block syntax.

They could also have just not used any keyword:

```
{
  let x = try foo()
} catch {
  // ...
}
```

They're also using `do` to introduce arbitrary nested scopes:

```
do {
  let x = foo()
}
```

Other languages already use braces without any keyword for this. Presumably they feel having a keyword makes the syntax easier to read or parse or something.